# input numbers into char array from file

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to build a `rpn` calculator which takes input from a file.

the input looks like `7 2 10 + -`

I want to put this input a char array which is dynamic memory. 
How do i add the numbers into my array ignoring the white spaces?

i tried using `fscanf(in,"%c", &input[i])`, but it is storing the white spaces as well as treating 10 and 1 and 0.

I am new to C and I have pretty basic knowledge of the subject any help will be deeply appreciated:) thank you

Comment: `10` and `'+'` are two different datatypes. You cannot store them in one array, unless you create a `union` with at least two data fields (for numbers and for operators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this exercise is not one a beginner should start with; It has a lot of pitfalls to consider, e.g. that a your input has to separate numbers from operators, that a valid number could be `-10` or even `+10` as well, that dealing with an unknown number of tokens is rather hard at the beginning, and so on.

Anyway, see the following code that solves at least the topic of reading in the file into an array of strings, thereby assuming up to 50 tokens with a length of at most 99 characters each. Other useful functions in this context might be `isdigit` and `atoi`; Hope it helps a bit.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FILE *f = fopen("data.txt", "rt");
    if (!f)
        return 0;

    char* tokens[50];
    int nrOfTokens = 0;

    char token[100];
    // fscanf(f, "%s", token) tries to read in the next token (separated by white space);
    // it returns 1 if exactly one token has been read in, otherwise 0
    while (nrOfTokens < 50 && fscanf(f, "%s", token)==1) {
        tokens[nrOfTokens] = strdup(token);  // strdup copies the content of `token` and allocates enough memory for this copy.
        nrOfTokens++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<nrOfTokens; i++) {
        printf("token: %s\n",tokens[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there any other way to achieve what strdup does? because when compiling with -std=c99, strdup throws a warning.

Comment: @akzh-- `strdup()` is not a C Standard Library function, but it is POSIX. You may need to enable it with a feature test macro, by adding this as the very first line of your source file: `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`. If `strdup()` is not available on your system, it is not difficult to implement, and you can find many examples online.